# How to omit column header in node.js using _.omit lodash?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

```
var reconwb = new Excel.Workbook();
var resws = reconwb.addWorksheet(RESCOL);
recdb.getCollection(RESCOL)
  .find()
  .forEach(row => {
      if (RESCOL) {
        if (!hdrsWritten) {
          reconwb.xlsx.writeFile(outputPath, orderedString(row, 'k', recCfg));
          hdrsWritten = true;
        }
        resws.columns = Object.keys(row).map((k) => ({
          header: k,
          key: k
        }));

        resws.addRow(_.omit(row, 'primaryKey', 'meta', '$loki'));
        // delete row['primaryKey'];
      }
```

[i shared my excel here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4dlE.png) I want to omit primaryKey, meta, and $loki headers how to do that? 
My code omits only the data of headers, i want to omit the column headers too.

Comment: Please share the code instead of image.

Comment: can you please share your JS object in code form?

Comment: @JoshulSharma ya i shared, have a look on it.

Comment: Just use _.omit on "resws.columns". Also, i suggest you use _.pick instead of _.omit as omit is slower. 
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#pick

Comment: it doesn't make any changes in my result when i use _.omit on "resws.columns"

Comment: if i am correct you are using 'exceljs' to read the excel sheet. This code line  resws.columns = Object.keys(row).map((k) => ({ header: k, key: k })); is what adds column headers. hence you need to omit here. For your reference see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs#columns

Comment: @JoshulSharma  Thank you! I got the solution.

Comment: @kiruthika glad to be of help!

Answer (score 1):

`_.omit` uses an array as a parameter [as per the docs](http://_.omit(object,%20[paths])), try:

```
resws.addRow(_.omit(row, ['primaryKey', 'meta', '$loki']))
```